# MainActivity is randomly refreshed, app crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

The Android app we are developing uses a `dataManager` object to handle communication with the required APIs and other related services. It's created in the `MainActivity` and then passed into the couple of fragments we have so they can use it as well. Recently we've been running into trouble where one of the fragments tries to access the `dataManager`, but it has inexplicably become `null`. This always seems to happen right after another event, which is shown here in Android Studio logs:

```
08-12 15:59:15.296      822-822/<name of our app> I/PhoneWindow﹕[generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001 08-12
08-12 15:59:15.296      822-822/<name of our app> I/PhoneWindow﹕[setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
```

Immediately after this happens, the app crashes because one of the fragments is trying to reference the `dataManager`, which is now `null`. I have never seen this error before, but I suspect that the `MainActivity` is being refreshed, because those two lines are also the very first thing that appear in the Android Studio logs. Is there some way I should handle the `MainActivity` being reloaded from scratch that preserves the current app state, or should I just reload the app somehow?

Comment: Check if not null and then try to refresh control state.

Comment: @dieter_h How would I refresh that? I'm somewhat new to Android and a quick Google search doesn't reveal much with those search terms.

Comment: `if(dataManager!=null){` do something - refresh `}`

Comment: @dieter_h well checking to see if it's null is easy enough, I'm already doing that. If it is null, how do I refresh state? Or am I supposed to be regularly refreshing to prevent it becoming null in the first place? Mainly I don't know what you mean by the term "refresh control state".

Comment: If it is null probably activity was destroyed and there is nothing to refresh.

Comment: @dieter_h that's rather bizarre. Is it possible for an activity to be destroyed while I am actively using it? It is not necessarily destroyed in the background.

Comment: When you turn on/off screen.

Comment: I think design the `datamanager` lifecycle following Activity life Lifecycle, is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The thrilling conclusion: I eventually tried rotating my phone with the app on it, which immediately and reliably triggered a crash. This means that Jiang YD was correct, and the app was not properly working with the Activity life cycle, and would crash whenever `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()` were called again. I'm now using a `Bundle` to preserve key state variables, so the app can handle such an event.